# Can't compare argv?

Tags: c, argv

I have this code:

```
if (argv[i] == "-n") 
{
    wait = atoi(argv[i + 1]);
}
else 
{
    printf("bad argument '%s'\n",argv[i]);
    exit(0);
}
```

When this code gets executed I get the following error:

> bad argument '-n'

I seriously don't know why it does that. Can someone explain?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

String comparisons need a function in C - usually `strcmp()` from `<string.h>`.

```
if (strcmp(argv[i], "-n") == 0) 
{
    wait = atoi(argv[i + 1]);
}
else 
{
    printf("bad argument '%s'\n",argv[i]);
    exit(0);
}
```

The `strcmp()` function returns a negative value (not necessarily -1) if the first argument sorts before the second; a positive value (not necessarily +1) if the first arguments sorts after the second; and zero if the two values are equal.

Answer (score 1):

The `==` operator does not work on the contents of strings because strings are effectively character pointers in this application, and the *pointer* get compared.

To compare the contents of strings use `strcmp` or `strncmp`.

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing pointers (`argv[i]` and of `"-n"` are a `char*` and a `const char*`).

Use `strcmp()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

What you're really doing here is pointer comparison. argv[i] is not a string, it's a pointer to a location in memory at which the actual string starts. Use strcmp().

Answer (score 0):

You're comparing pointers, not string contents.  `argv[i]` and `"-n"` are two different strings, stored at two different locations in memory, even if the characters inside the strings are equal.

Answer (score 0):

In C, the operator `==` compares for equality.

Values of the same numeric type are compared the straightforward way (i.e. `2 + 2 == 4` is true).

Values of different integer (and non-integer numeric) types undergo some conversion.  See elsewhere.

Pointers are equal if the point at the same address.

String literals are placed in memory not overlapping any other thing; including not overlapping anything pointed to by argv[i] (for i = 0 to argc).

So you're comparing two unequal pointers; that's why.  You want to use `if (!strcmp(argv[i], "-n")) { ... }`.

Answer (score 0):

```
int equal(char* stringa, char* stringb) {
    while((*stringa) && (*stringb)) {
        if(*stringa!=*stringb)
            return FALSE;
        stringa++;
        stringb++;
    }
    return TRUE;
}
```

is also working for me